# Heroku rails angular js compiling assets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, heroku, ruby-on-rails-4

I got problem deploying my js file to heroku.
Problem started when I added component for my angular module like this 
`var keysApp = angular.module('keys',['mgo-angular-wizard']);`

So the code in application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require_directory ./bootstrap
//= require mandrill/json2
//= require mandrill/mandrill.min
//= require libs/underscore-min
//= require angular/angular
//= require angular/angular-wizard.min

(function(){
    var keysApp = angular.module('keys',['mgo-angular-wizard']);

    keysApp.controller('KeysServiceController', function($scope){


        $scope.keysServiceModel = keysServicePriceGlobal;


        $scope.chosen = "";

        $scope.chosenPoint = "";

        $scope.userName = undefined;
        $scope.userEmail = undefined;
        $scope.userPhone = undefined;


        var myMap;
        var myGroup;


        var orderMailer = new mandrill.Mandrill('');

        ymaps.ready(init);

        function init(){

            myMap = new ymaps.Map("map", { center: [59.939095,30.315868],  zoom: 10  });

            myGroup = new ymaps.GeoObjectCollection({}, {
                draggable: false
            });


            function addObjectToKeyMap(place) {
                var geocoder = new ymaps.geocode( place.address, { results: 1 } );
                geocoder.then(function (res) {
                    place.coords = res.geoObjects.get(0).geometry.getCoordinates();
                    myGroup.add(new ymaps.Placemark(place.coords,{
                        balloonContentBody: place.address,
                        id: place.id
                    }));

                });
            }

            for(i=0; i< keysDotsModelGlobal.length; i++){
                addObjectToKeyMap(keysDotsModelGlobal[i]);
            }

            myMap.geoObjects.add(myGroup);

            myGroup.events.add("click",function(e){
                var object = e.get('target');
                var idOfClickedPlacemark = object.properties.get('id');
                var r = $.grep(keysDotsModelGlobal, function(e){ return e.id == idOfClickedPlacemark; });
                $scope.editChosenPoint(r[0]);
            })


        }

        $scope.editChosenPoint = function(point){
            $scope.chosenPoint = point;
            $scope.$apply();
        };


        $scope.choose = function (service) {
            if($scope.isChosen(service)){
                $scope.chosen = undefined;
            } else {
                $scope.chosen = service;
            }
        };

        $scope.isChosen = function(service){
            return $scope.chosen === service;
        };


        $scope.isHeader = function(service){
            return service.type == "hr";
        };

        $scope.closeChosenProduct = function(){
            $scope.chosen = undefined;
        };

        $scope.closeChosenAddress = function(){
            $scope.chosenPoint = undefined;
        };

        $scope.sendOrderRequest = function(){
            orderMailer.messages.send({
                }
            }, function(res){
                console.log(res);
            }, function(err){
                console.log(err)
            })
        }
    });
})();
```

In development everythin is cool. 
But in production i got

> Unknown provider error

.

my production.rb

```
  config.serve_static_assets = true

  # Compress JavaScripts and CSS.   
config.assets.js_compressor = false
 # config.assets.css_compressor = :sass
```

I think it compresses js-files regardless of the settings in the file production.rb

Comment: Does the application run with this command - rails s -e production

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have same issue with my angular app in production mode. Below change works for me.

```
config.assets.js_compressor = Uglifier.new(mangle: false)
```

Answer (score 2):

Adding these to the Gemfile worked for me on rails 3

```
gem 'heroku'
gem 'rails_12factor'
gem 'rails_log_stdout', github: 'heroku/rails_log_stdout'
gem 'rails3_serve_static_assets', github: 'heroku/rails3_serve_static_assets'
```

Worth a try though in your case

Answer (score 0):

u also need to add `//= require self` to include the js included in `application.js`